# Error in inserting leading zeroes in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use this code to add leading zeroes.

```
SELECT RIGHT('HL000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @holrefno + 1), 10) AS 'refno'
```

But when I tested it, let's say I'll make the reference number as 99 it would show up as `HL00000100`. I want to keep it as a 10 digit string in my database, could anyone refer me my mistake? Or is there any way I could fix this?

EDIT:

I would like to have an input where the string length will still be 10.

Comment: er... add another two 0's to your string: `'HL00000000'`

Comment: still not the answer, because the string length becomes 11 instead of 10

Comment: The result of `right(x,10)` cannot be a string of length 11. It can only be a string of length 10

Comment: Do the 10 digits you want _include_ or _exclude_ the HL part? "HL00000100" is a ten digit code including the HL part.

Comment: Can `@holrefno` ever be less than -1 or greater than 999998?

Comment: It can not be less than 1 sirm but it could reach 999999, but its another problem sir. as of now, i just want a 10 length string as a reference number .

Comment: And doesn't my answer below do what you need?

Comment: sorry sir for the late reply, but i checked your answer sir, and it went well! thanks sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove the 'HL' part of the `right` function (therefore also limit your `varchar` to 8), and also add a '0' in case `@holrefno` is less than 9.

```
SELECT 'HL' + right('0000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @holrefno + 1), 8) AS 'refno'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one is working even though **@holrefno** is null

```
declare @holrefno int
--set @holrefno = 56784

SELECT 'HL' + right('0000000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), @holrefno + 1), 8) AS 'refno'
```

Comment: That looks pretty much like the accepted answer. ;) I bet you meant `ISNULL(@holrefno, 0)`.